# Pass a connected component into React Route causing error

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

When I pass a connected component `export default connect(ComponentName)` to a React Route `route` like code below,

```
<Route path={path} component={ComponentName}/>
```

I get the following errors,

```
You must pass a component to the function returned by connect. 
Instead received {"match":{"path":"/:code","url":"/sample-
code","isExact":true,"params":{"code":"sample-code"}},"location":
{"pathname":"/sample-code","search":"","hash":""},"history":
{"length":40,"action":"POP","location":{"pathname":"/sample-
code","search":"","hash":""}}}
```

Can I pass a connected component to `route` component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`connect` take as its arguments functions like `mapStateToProps`. You probably meant `connect()(ComponentName)`.

You can definitely pass a connected component to a route with the `component` prop, no need to use something like the `render` prop.

Comment: Haha an easy mistake. It's a function that takes a function and returns a function which you then have to call with your own function!

Comment: Will accept your answer in 10mins. Thank you for spotting the mistake.